# Parsing html using lxml.html

Tags: python, parsing, screen-scraping, lxml

I'm developing a Python scraper at scraperwiki.com and I need to parse a html page that containt the following:

```
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
       ItemLine1 ItemLine1 ItemLine1
       <br> 
       ItemLine2 ItemLine2 ItemLine2
 </div>
 <br>
</div>
```

What I'm doing now is:

```
import scraperwiki
import lxml.html

#.......................
raw_string = lxml.html.fromstring(scraperwiki.scrape(url_to_scrape))
my_line = ((raw_string.cssselect("div.items div.item")[0]).text)
print (my_line)
```

and it prints `ItemLine1 ItemLine1 ItemLine1` only. When I change [0] to [1] it throws an exception.

How do I scrape that? Should I use xpath?

Comment: My guess is that the issue here is that the br is opened but not closed.

Comment: beautysoup is not acceptable. <<br is opened but not closed>> maybe, so what? I have to parse it anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XPath is the most straightforward solution:

```
items = raw_string.cssselect('div.items div.item')

texts = [item.xpath('br[1]/preceding-sibling::node()') for item in items]
```

The XPath `br[1]` selects the first `br` child of `div.item`; The `preceding-sibling::` axis contains all nodes that occur before the first `br`; `node()` selects every kind of node (text or elements) that are in that axis.

If your larger goal is to split up the children of a node by `br` elements, you can take a few different approaches. The reason this is so tricky is that elements like `br` and `hr` are badly designed markup. Using a tree-like markup language like sgml, html, or xml, things that should be together should be grouped by a common parent element rather than split by a childless delimiter element.

I'll expand your test case to demonstrate some more complex situations:

```
html = """<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
   <br>
   ItemLine1 ItemLine1 ItemLine1
   <a href="">item</a>
   Itemline1-b
   <br> 
   <a class="z">item2</a>
   ItemLine2 ItemLine2 ItemLine2
   <br><br>
   Itemline3
 </div>
 <br>
</div>"""

doc = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
itemlist = doc.cssselect('div.items div.item')
```

The first approach is to simply get all nodes in the paragraph and split them into different lists by `br`. If you use this approach, don't use the `text` and `tail` attributes of the ElementTree API because you will probably end up duplicating text.

```
def paras_by_br_nodes(parent):
    """Return a list of node children of parent (including text nodes) grouped by "paragraphs" which are delimited by <br/> elements."""
    paralist = []
    paras = []
    for node in parent.xpath('node()'):
        if getattr(node, 'tag', None) == 'br':
            paralist.append(paras)
            paras = []
        else:
            paras.append(node)
        paralist.append(paras)
        return paralist


print paras_by_br_nodes(itemlist[0])
```

This produces lists like so:

```
[['\n       '],
 ['\n       ItemLine1 ItemLine1 ItemLine1\n\t\t', <Element a at 0x10498a350>, '\n\t\tItemline1-b\n       '],
 [<Element a at 0x10498a230>, '\n       ItemLine2 ItemLine2 ItemLine2\n       '],
 [], 
 ['\n       Itemline3\n ']]
```

A second approach is to make use of the ElementTree API and keep text nodes in the `text` and `tail` attributes. The downside of this approach is that if there is no element to attach the text, we need to just include the text node. This list of non-homogenous types is a bit more trouble to work with.

```
def paras_by_br_text(parent):
    paralist=[]
    para=[parent.text]
    for item in parent:
        if item.tag=='br':
            paralist.append(para)
            para = [item.tail]
        else:
            para.append(item)
    paralist.append(para)
    return paralist

print paras_by_br_text(itemlist[0])
```

This produces a list like so. Note that in contrast to the previous list it only has text nodes nodes in the first position of the list. This corresponds to the `br.tail` text or `parent.text` (which is text before the first element).

```
[['\n       '],
 ['\n       ItemLine1 ItemLine1 ItemLine1\n\t\t', <Element a at 0x1042f5170>],
 [<Element a at 0x1042f5290>],
 [],
 ['\n       Itemline3\n ']]
```

I think the best approach is to introduce new elements. This html is using `br` when it should be using `p` or some other container element. So instead, let's *fix the html* and return a list of elements instead of a list of list of nodes:

```
def paras_by_br(parent):
    paralist = []
    para = lxml.html.etree.Element('para')
    if parent.text:
        para.text = parent.text
    for item in parent:
        if item.tag=='br':
            paralist.append(para)
            para = lxml.html.etree.Element('para')
            if item.tail:
                para.text = item.tail
        else:
            para.append(item)
    return paralist

paralist = paras_by_br(itemlist[0])

print "\n--------\n".join(lxml.html.etree.tostring(para) for para in paralist)
```

This prints the following:

```
<para>
       </para>
--------
<para>
       ItemLine1 ItemLine1 ItemLine1
        <a href="">item</a>
        Itemline1-b
       </para>
--------
<para><a class="z">item2</a>
       ItemLine2 ItemLine2 ItemLine2
       </para>
--------
<para/>
```

See how items are grouped by a new `para` element, which doesn't exist in the original document.

Comment: Thanks, but it also returns only `ItemLine1 ItemLine1 ItemLine1`. What about `item2item2...`?

Comment: I thought that's all you wanted? I will expand the answer with a solution that groups them.